# R dplyr - select values from one column based on position of a specific value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with gait-cycle data. I have 8 events marked for each id and gait trial. The values "LFCH" and "RFCH" occurs twice in each trial, as these represent the beginning and the end of the gait cycles from left and right leg.

Sample Data Frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:5, each = 16),
                 Gait_nr = rep(1:2, each = 8, times=5),
                 Frame = rep(c(1,5,7,9,10,15,22,25), times = 10),
                 Marks = rep(c("LFCH", "LHL", "RFCH", "LTO", "RHL", "LFCH", "RTO", "RFCH"), times =10) 

head(df,8)
  ID Gait_nr Frame Marks
1  1       1     1  LFCH
2  1       1     5   LHL
3  1       1     7  RFCH
4  1       1     9   LTO
5  1       1    10   RHL
6  1       1    15  LFCH
7  1       1    22   RTO
8  1       1    25  RFCH
```

I wold like to create something like

```
Total_gait_left = Frame[The last time Marks == "LFCH"] - Frame[The first time Marks == "LFCH"]
```

My current code solves the problem, but depends on the position of the Frame values rather than actual values in Marks. Any individual not following the normal gait pattern will have wrong values produced by the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
l <- df %>% group_by(ID, Gait_nr) %>% filter(grepl("L.+", Marks)) %>%
  summarize(Total_gait = Frame[4] - Frame[1],
            Side = "left")

r <- df %>% group_by(ID, Gait_nr) %>% filter(grepl("R.+", Marks)) %>%
  summarize(Total_gait = Frame[4] - Frame[1],
            Side = "right")

val <- union(l,r, by=c("ID", "Gait_nr", "Side")) %>% arrange(ID, Gait_nr, Side)
```

Can you help me make my code more stable by helping me change e.g. Frame[4] to something like Frame[Marks=="LFCH" the last time ]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `LFCH` and `RFCH` happen exactly twice, you can filter and then use `diff` in `summarize`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(ID, Gait_nr) %>% 
    summarise(
        left = diff(Frame[Marks == 'LFCH']), 
        right = diff(Frame[Marks == 'RFCH'])
    )

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID [?]
#      ID Gait_nr  left right
#   <int>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1       1    14    18
# 2     1       2    14    18
# 3     2       1    14    18
# 4     2       2    14    18
# 5     3       1    14    18
# 6     3       2    14    18
# 7     4       1    14    18
# 8     4       2    14    18
# 9     5       1    14    18
#10     5       2    14    18
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `first` and `last` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(Marks %in% "LFCH") %>%
  group_by(ID, Gait_nr) %>%
  summarise(Total_gait = last(Frame) - first(Frame)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#       ID Gait_nr Total_gait
#    <int>   <int>      <dbl>
#  1     1       1         14
#  2     1       2         14
#  3     2       1         14
#  4     2       2         14
#  5     3       1         14
#  6     3       2         14
#  7     4       1         14
#  8     4       2         14
#  9     5       1         14
# 10     5       2         14
```